# Migrate to Go modules while keep on using distribution packages

Tags: go, go-modules

I have a GOPATH based project that I currently build like this on Fedora:

```
sudo dnf install golang-etcd-bbolt-devel golang-x-sys-devel golang-x-text-devel
GOPATH=$HOME/go:/usr/share/gocode go build
```

My project ([gonzofilter](https://github.com/gsauthof/gonzofilter)) implements a command line utility and thus source files are located in the main package (i.e. they have  a `package main` declaration).

With Fedora 34 and beyond it seems that Go removed support for building GOPATH style projects and one really has to use Go modules:

```
go build
go: cannot find main module; see 'go help modules'
```

That [Go blog post](https://blog.golang.org/migrating-to-go-modules#TOC_4.) kind of covers my case (-> 'Without a dependency manager'), but it doesn't explicitly mention how to deal with main package projects or with distribution provided dependencies.

So, how do I migrate such a project?

How do I have to tell Go/`go mod tidy` to look for my dependencies under `/usr/share/gocode`?

---

**Edit:** To be precise: Fedora 34 comes with Go 1.16 which 'just' changed the `GO111MODULE` default from `auto` to `on`. Thus, one still can restore the old behavior by setting `GO111MODULE=auto`.

However, Golang developers already [announced](https://blog.golang.org/go116-module-changes) that they want to drop support for GOPATH style projects in Go 1.17:

> We plan to drop support for GOPATH mode in Go 1.17. In other words, Go 1.17 will ignore GO111MODULE. If you have projects that do not build in module-aware mode, now is the time to migrate.

---

**Update 2023-02-19:** As of Go 1.19.5 (Fedora 37), `GO111MODULE=off` still works for building GOPATH style (i.e. non-modularized) projects. Example:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go:/usr/share/gocode GOPROXY=off GO111MODULE=off
go build helloworld.go
```

Apparently, the Go team adjusted their GO11MODULE deprecation plan, without [targeting any new future release for removal, yet](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GOPATH).

Comment: Don't rely on a Linux distro's version of Go. Install the [precise version](https://golang.org/doc/install) for your needs. To turn go modules off for builds i.e. use GOPATH builds set the env var : `GO111MODULE=off` (note this option will disappear in go 1.17 released later this year)

Comment: @colm.anseo I don't see how installing another Go version would help me accomplishing my stated objective which is to keep on using the distribution packages ... And yeah, I already mentioned `GO11MODULE` in my answer and I mentioned how disabling modules likely only is a possible work-around until Go 1.17, as well.

Comment: I started crafting my comment before your edit. The reason I mentioned installing an explicit Go version is because linux distro's are notoriously back-level with their Go versions - so rather than hope you get a recent version - take the guess work out.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicity define using replace keyword in your generated mod file to refer to your local modules.

`replace packagename => /usr/share/gcode`

Comment: Hm, this doesn't help with `go mod tidy` which ignores the locally available modules and downloads them from the net instead ...

Comment: I believe you got it fixed. I see your answer below.

Answer (score 0):

One way to migrate such a GOPATH project to a Go modules aware one is the following:

First, manually create the `go.mod` with the direct dependencies:

```
module github.com/gsauthof/gonzofilter

go 1.15

require (
    go.etcd.io/bbolt  v1.3.5
    golang.org/x/sys  v0.0.0-20210423185535-09eb48e85fd7
    golang.org/x/text v0.3.5
)
```

I got the minimal versions from what's currently on my system:

```
$ rpm -q golang-etcd-bbolt-devel golang-x-sys-devel golang-x-text-devel golang-bin
golang-etcd-bbolt-devel-1.3.5-2.fc33.noarch
golang-x-sys-devel-0-0.39.20210123git9b0068b.fc33.noarch
golang-x-text-devel-0.3.5-1.fc33.noarch
golang-bin-1.15.8-1.fc33.x86_64
```

The problem now is that one can't simply tell the module-aware Go tools to look for those modules under the filesystem path `/usr/share/gocode/src` where they are all located.

There is the `replace` directive one can add to our `go.mod` file to set the lookup path for single dependencies, e.g. like this:

```
replace (
    go.etcd.io/bbolt  => /usr/share/gocode/src/go.etcd.io/bbolt
    golang.org/x/sys  => /usr/share/gocode/src/golang.org/x/sys
    golang.org/x/text => /usr/share/gocode/src/golang.org/x/text
)
```

However, a `go build` still doesn't use *indirect* dependencies from `/usr/share/gocode`, e.g. the ones that are provided by the packages `golang-x-text-devel` depends on. In this example, `go build` does find `/usr/share/gocode/src/golang.org/x/text/go.mod` but that file doesn't include any `replace` directive.

Thus, this fails:

```
$ GOPROXY=off go build -mod=readonly
go: golang.org/x/text@v0.3.6 requires
    golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20180917221912-90fa682c2a6e: module lookup disabled
       by GOPROXY=off
```

To resolve this we have to add replace directive lines also for all indirect dependencies.

Doing this manually is tedious and error prone, of course.

Thus, we can automate this with a small shell one-liner:

We start with this `go.mod` file:

```
module github.com/gsauthof/gonzofilter

go 1.15

require (
    go.etcd.io/bbolt v1.3.5
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20210423185535-09eb48e85fd7
    golang.org/x/text v0.3.6
)

replace (
//replace-this
)
```

The following fixpoint iteration then adds dependencies until the build succeeds:

```
while true; do
    GOPROXY=off go build -mod readonly 2> t
    if [ $? -eq 1 ] && grep 'module lookup disabled\|missing go.sum entry' t >/dev/null; then
        x=$(grep 'disabled\|missing' t |  tr ' \t' '\n'   | grep '@' | head -n1 | cut -d'@' -f1 )
        echo "Adding $x"
        sed -i "s@^\(//replace-this\)@\t$x => /usr/share/gocode/src/$x\n\1@" go.mod
        continue
    fi
    break
done
```

Which results in the following require directive for this example project:

```
replace (
    go.etcd.io/bbolt => /usr/share/gocode/src/go.etcd.io/bbolt
    golang.org/x/sys => /usr/share/gocode/src/golang.org/x/sys
    golang.org/x/text => /usr/share/gocode/src/golang.org/x/text
    golang.org/x/tools => /usr/share/gocode/src/golang.org/x/tools
    github.com/yuin/goldmark => /usr/share/gocode/src/github.com/yuin/goldmark
    golang.org/x/mod => /usr/share/gocode/src/golang.org/x/mod
    golang.org/x/net => /usr/share/gocode/src/golang.org/x/net
    golang.org/x/sync => /usr/share/gocode/src/golang.org/x/sync
    golang.org/x/xerrors => /usr/share/gocode/src/golang.org/x/xerrors
    golang.org/x/crypto => /usr/share/gocode/src/golang.org/x/crypto
    golang.org/x/term => /usr/share/gocode/src/golang.org/x/term
//replace-this
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, distributions should package installed dependencies in a layout that is compatible with the [`GOPROXY` protocol](https://golang.org/ref/mod#goproxy-protocol). Then you would be able to set `GOPROXY` appropriately and run `go mod tidy` to use the installed dependencies.

However, to my knowledge, no distributions actually provide a `GOPROXY` tree at this point. You may need a workaround.

---

The next best alternative is to wire up the replacements yourself using `replace` directives. `go mod tidy` already knows to prefer the versions found in `replace` directives over other versions, so it should suffice to do something like:

```sh
go mod init github.com/gsauthof/gonzofilter

go mod edit -replace go.etcd.io/bbolt=/usr/share/gocode/src/go.etcd.io/bbolt
go mod edit -replace golang.org/x/sys=/usr/share/gocode/src/golang.org/x/sys
go mod edit -replace golang.org/x/text=/usr/share/gocode/src/golang.org/x/text

go mod tidy
```

However, note that the `replace` directive requires the target to include an explicit `go.mod` file, so this will only work if either your dependencies already have explicit `go.mod` files or your distro packager has added them as a patch to support this use-case.

---

Note that with those `replace` directives in place, your build would not be [reproducible](https://research.swtch.com/vgo-repro#reproducible_builds) or [repeatable](https://research.swtch.com/vgo-principles#repeatability) over time: if you change the distro-installed versions of your dependencies, then the meaning of `go build` will silently change to use those different (and possibly incompatible!) versions as well.

So I would recommend that you not do that, and instead use `go get` and/or `go mod tidy` to fetch the specific module versions you want from upstream or from a public module proxy (such as `proxy.golang.org`).

If you are concerned about upstream tampering, note that the Go project's [official binary distribution](https://golang.org/dl/) of the `go` command — and the `go` command built from pristine source — by default automatically verifies checksums for downloaded modules against an auditable public database at https://sum.golang.org; however, the Fedora distribution of the `go` command [disables use of the checksum database by default](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/golang1.13#Detailed_Description).

Answer (score -1):

Another way to point Go to the system-wide available dependencies is to exploit Go's module vendoring support: That means by symbolically linking the module file paths, creating a minimal `vendor/modules.txt` and compiling with `-mod vendor`.

So with `-mod vendor` Go build doesn't try to download any required modules, instead it looks them up in `vendor/` directory.

One might be tempted to just create a symbolic link that points from `vendor/` to `/usr/share/gocode/src` (where all the distributions `golang-...-devel` packages are installed), but this doesn't work because `-mod vendor` also requires yet another modules description file, i.e. `vendor/modules.txt`.

So, besides some more specific symlinks, we have to create a proper `modules.txt` when using the vendoring feature:

First, to create all the sublevel symlinks:

```
awk -vvd=wendor 'BEGIN {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc";
    system("mkdir -p "vd)
}
func push_mod(pkg) {
    if (!seen[pkg]) {
        ARGV[ARGC++]="/usr/share/gocode/src/"pkg"/go.mod";
        seen[pkg]=1;
    }
    sub("/.+$", "", pkg);
    xs[pkg]=1;
}
/^require[^(]+$/ {
    push_mod($2);
    next
}
/^require/ {
    inb=1;
    next
}
/^\)/ {
    inb=0;
    next
}
inb { 
    push_mod($1);
}
END {
    for (i in xs) {
        print i;
        system("ln -sfn /usr/share/gocode/src/"i" "vd"/"i)
    }
}' go.mod
```

Then, to create the `vendor/modules.txt`:

```
awk -vvd=wendor 'BEGIN {
    fn=vd"/modules.txt"
}
/^require/ {
    inb=1;
    next
}
/^\)/ {
    inb=0;
    next
}
inb {
    printf("# %s %s\n## explicit\n%s\n", $1, $2, $1) > fn 
}' go.mod
```

After those commands, the vendor directory looks like this for our example project:

```
$ ls -l vendor
total 16
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 juser juser  32 2021-04-25 11:12 github.com -> /usr/share/gocode/src/github.com
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 juser juser  32 2021-04-25 11:12 go.etcd.io -> /usr/share/gocode/src/go.etcd.io
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 juser juser  32 2021-04-25 11:12 golang.org -> /usr/share/gocode/src/golang.org
-rw-r--r--. 1 juser juser 195 2021-04-25 11:13 modules.txt
$ cat vendor/modules.txt
# go.etcd.io/bbolt v1.3.5
## explicit
go.etcd.io/bbolt
# golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20210423185535-09eb48e85fd7
## explicit
golang.org/x/sys
# golang.org/x/text v0.3.5
## explicit
golang.org/x/text
```

Whereas `go.mod` is quite minimal, i.e. it doesn't contain any replace directive:

```
module github.com/gsauthof/gonzofilter

go 1.15

require (
    go.etcd.io/bbolt  v1.3.5
    golang.org/x/sys  v0.0.0-20210423185535-09eb48e85fd7
    golang.org/x/text v0.3.5
)
```

And this is sufficient to let

```
GOPROXY=off go build -mod vendor
```

succeed.

Note that indirect dependencies such as `golang.org/x/tools` aren't listed in the `modules.txt`, however, they are still available via `vendor/` because we transitively traversed all `go.mod` files starting with the required modules when creating symlinks to the top level directories.

The discrete charme of this scheme is that one doesn't have to mess with `replace` directives in the `go.mod` file. That means `go.mod` can be kept quite generic, one basically just have to add the `-mod vendor` switch to the build command.

Comment: I recommend that you only construct `vendor/modules.txt` files using the `go mod vendor` command. The format is backward-compatible over time but new versions of the `go` command can (and do) expect new information to be added over time. For example, the [vendoring changes in Go 1.14](https://golang.org/doc/go1.14#go-command) started enforcing stronger invariants, and Go 1.17 expects language version annotations for dependenices.